# Is it possible to read logcat in native C?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, logcat

I've seen a lot of different ways in Java to dump Android logcat messages to a file, but I haven't been able to find a way of doing it in C.

Is it possible to programmatically retrieve the messages in C and dump them to a file?

Comment: Note that as of Android 4.1, you will only be able to read your own process' messages, unless your app is installed on the system partition (e.g., rooted device user). Also note that reading LogCat programmatically on-device has never been officially endorsed by Google. http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/12/read-logs-regression.html

Comment: @CommonsWare : So the app can only read its own log messages but if you do it from a shell you can read all log messages? How does that make sense? Valentin's suggestion to create a child logcat process would give me all logcat messages wouldn't it?

Comment: "if you do it from a shell you can read all log messages?" -- if by "shell" you mean `adb shell`, then yes. "How does that make sense?" -- `adb shell` runs as a user that has access to all of LogCat. Your app does not, by default. "Valentin's suggestion to create a child logcat process would give me all logcat messages wouldn't it?" -- only if your app is installed on the system partition and therefore can hold the `READ_LOGS` permission. It might also work if your app runs with superuser privileges (e.g., by a rooted device user).

Comment: @Commonsware: so there's no way to programmatically simulate (from native C) calling logcat from an adb shell; i.e. getting the same amount of information from logcat programmatically that one would obtain by opening adb shell and calling logcat? (unless the app runs with superuser privileges or is installed on a system partition)

Comment: AFAIK, you are correct in your analysis. To put it another way, if you can do what you are seeking to do, that would represent a privacy and security hole that would need to be fixed.

Comment: CommonsWare is correct.  You can see from the logcat sources (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/kitkat-release/logcat/logcat.cpp) that there's no permission-checking in the command itself; the kernel driver simply won't give you the logs from another app unless you have the right privs.  On a rooted device you could `su -c logcat` to run the shell command with elevated privileges.

Comment: @fadden do you by chance know what kernel driver does this? I was studying the android specific changes, wanted to know how this is implemented

Comment: @CommonsWare *if you if you can do what you are seeking to do, that would represent a privacy and security hole that would need to be fixed*: why? If App `A` outputs something to logcat, why would it matter if another app can read it?

Comment: @Adrian: Because developers log stupid stuff. For example, a major US airline used to log all the JSON they got back from their Web service calls. I know this, because I had that airline's app, and I could see that output in LogCat. There were details in that JSON that I would rather not be distributed to arbitrary apps, such as upcoming travel plans, frequent-flyer numbers, and the like.

Comment: @CommonsWare ***"adb shell runs as a user that has access to all Logcat"***: how does this work? Is it possible to spoof this?

Comment: @Adrian: "Is it possible to spoof this?" -- I sure hope not.

Comment: @CommonsWare what's the mechanism for this (if I were to google it)? How does "adb shell" magically get this special permission? Is it some secret handshake that is builtin to the kernel and android studio?

Comment: @Adrian: I do not know the details, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Create a child logcat process, read its stdout and use cstdio to save data to a file.

In that way Android isn't different from any other linux distributive.